# Updating sqlite3 dababase from tkinter frame

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, label

I am trying to update my sqlite3 database with this function but I can't seem the pass the parameters correctly. Person is picked up by a selection that is made in the tkinter frame manually.

```
def updateContact():
    person = select.get(ACTIVE)
    conn.execute("UPDATE Table set NAME =? WHERE NAME = ?",(nameVar.get(), (person,)))
    conn.execute("UPDATE Table set PHONE =? WHERE NAME = ?",(phoneVar.get(), (person,)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass parameters in a *single non-nested tuple*:

```
conn.execute("UPDATE Table set NAME = ? WHERE NAME = ?", (nameVar.get(), person))
```

Comment: Actually, found my answer, it wasn't updating in DB because lack of .commit() *ragequit*

Comment: @user65465218 ah, wanted to include a note about commit call, but decided it is not relevant. Okay, but this is the way you should be passing parameters.